# How to partially apply the flip function?

Tags: haskell

I am a little confused about what the "partial" application of flip might do.

Since the type of the `flip` function is:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

which we can write without the parenthesis as:

```
flip :: a -> b -> c -> b -> a -> c
```

How can I partially apply it to only the first argument `a`? To get a function with the type:

```
flipa ::     b -> c -> b -> a -> c
```

Or it doesn't make sense?

For example if I have something like:

```
let foo a b = (Just a, b)
:t foo
> foo:: a -> t -> (Maybe a, t)
```

It makes sense to partially apply it:

```
let a = foo 1
:t a
a :: t -> (Maybe Integer, t)
```

Comment: `(->)` is right-associative, not left-associative: the `flipa` you describe is an entirely different function (AFAIK the type dictates it must be `flipa _ x _ _ = x`).

Comment: Another view of why aren't these two equivalent: let's take `f :: (a → a) → a` and `g :: a → a → a`. By Curry-Howard isomorphism, `g` represents theorem `a ⇒ a ⇒ a`, i.e. if `a` is true, then `a` implies `a` (which is true; it can be derived from `a ⇒ (b ⇒ a)` (axiom of intuitionistic logic)). On the other hand, `(a ⇒ a) ⇒ a` tells us nothing about `a` (if `a` implies `a` then `a`; but as you can see, `a` could also be false and `a ⇒ a` still holds). Indeed, if you have `f :: (a → a) → a`, you can prove that false is true: `boom :: False; boom = f id` (where False is empty data type)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It doesn't make sense. The signature

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

is equivalent to

```
f :: a -> (b -> c)
```

and not equivalent to

```
f :: (a -> b) -> c
```

---

This convention is why you can partially apply function in Haskell in the first place. Since all functions are curried by default, the signature `f :: a -> b -> c` can be interpreted as

> *f takes **a** and **b**, and returns **c***

or can equally validly be interpreted as

> *f takes **a**, and returns a function that takes **b** and returns **c***

Comment: Hm.. what about a simple function as see in my updated question.

Comment: What's your question about that function?

Comment: "Partial application" is a valid synonym for "currying"

Comment: I was under the impression that they were different concepts, e.g. see [here](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk). I have clarified my answer, though.

Comment: Well, yes, considering function `(a × b × c) → d`, currying turns it into `a → b → c → d`, while partial application fixes any of the arguments into function `(b × c) → d` (or other pair depending on the argument being applied).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor The question is that I can do partial application with that simple function, why can't I do it with the more complicated function?

Comment: You can partially apply the flip function, but you partially apply it to the *first* argument (which is of type `a -> b -> c`).

Comment: @drozzy: You can and you in fact already did! Imagine that flip has type `d → b → a → c`, where `d` must be a function of type `a → b → c`. If you apply `flip` to a function `f` of type `d`, you get back a new function `b → a → c` with the `d` argument fixed.

Comment: @Vitus where is your answer? I find your commends to be great explanations.

Answer (score 7):

`(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c` is not the same as `a -> b -> c -> b -> a -> c` because the `->` operator is right-associative, not left-associative. Therefore, partially applying `flip` is meaningless because it only has one parameter in the first place.

Also, your example doesn't make much sense because it would still produce an output function taking an `a`, which you would presumably not want. But if you take that out, you get a function which takes a unary function and produces exactly the same unary function, so just partially apply the original function and you're done.

Comment: I see three parameters :D (but surely, not five!)

Comment: It depends how you look at it, but in its normal usage flip has one parameter and produces a function which takes two parameters. Of course in Haskell because of currying this is exactly the same as partially applying a function that takes three parameters.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, the type `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c` is *not* the same as `a -> b -> c -> b -> a -> c`.

However, it *is* the same as `(a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)`.

That shows that `flip` is a function that takes a single argument as input and therefore can't be partially applied*.

---

*: from the point of view of that `flip` returns a function of type `b -> a -> c`, which is not the only valid point of view in Haskell.

Comment: Why is it the same as `(a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)`? How come you can take the parenthesis of the last triple, but not the first?

Comment: @drozzy -- [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#higher-orderism) says `because functions are curried by default, the second pair of parentheses is really unnecessary, because -> is right associative by default. (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c) is the same as (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> (a -> c)), which is the same as (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`.  So it's because of the associativity of `->`.

Comment: @drozzy: That's because `->` is right associative. In other words, `a → (b → (c → (d → e)))` is the same as `a → b → c → d → e`. As an example, division on real numbers is left associative, that means `((5 / 4) / 3) / 2 = 5 / 4 / 3 / 2` but not `5 / (4 / (3 / 2))`. edit: perhaps even more suggestive example: `(5 / 4) / (3 / 2) ≠ 5 / 4 / 3 / 2`